# FLUTTER - Android 4.4 - SdkVersion 19 - Aplicativo fechando ao abrir WebView

Tags: flutter, versionamento, android-webview

Estou tendo alguns problemas com a utilização do WebView (Plugin flutter_inappwebview ou webview_flutter) para dispositivos com o android 4.4 (SdkVersion 19), após a finalização do carregamento do webview a aplicação simplesmente é fechada, sem apresentar algum erro no qual de para identificar do que se trata o problema.

Nas versões mais atuais do Android, como 5.0 por exemplo, webview funciona e é carregado normalmente sem nenhum problema, entendo que trata-se da versão, mas precisava que funcionasse na 4.4 também.

Deixo o meu git com o código caso alguém possa ajudar: https://github.com/leoblanski/flutter_webview_tests_erro

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
D/dalvikvm( 3928): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 472K, 17% free 5541K/6664K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 3928): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.982MB for 7750092-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 3928): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 13109K/14236K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 3928): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 3928): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 13111K/14236K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 3928): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.375MB for 7750092-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 3928): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 20680K/21808K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 3928): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 20680K/21808K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
I/chromium( 3928): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
I/chromium( 3928): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
D/EGL_emulation( 3928): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8bfbfa0: ver 3 0
D/EGL_emulation( 3928): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8bfbfa0: ver 3 0
W/ImageReader_JNI( 3928): Unable to acquire a lockedBuffer, very likely client tries to lock more than maxImages buffers
E/flutter ( 3928): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(182)] java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (3) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:346)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.media.ImageReader.acquireLatestImage(ImageReader.java:242)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterImageView.acquireLatestImage(FlutterImageView.java:175)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.acquireLatestImageViewFrame(FlutterView.java:1182)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.onEndFrame(PlatformViewsController.java:874)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onEndFrame(FlutterJNI.java:1032)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/flutter ( 3928):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 3928):
F/flutter ( 3928): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1429)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
F/libc    ( 3928): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000f58 (code=-6), thread 3928 (utter_innapview)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/google_sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/6761301:eng/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 3928, tid: 3928, name: utter_innapview  >>> com.example.flutter_innapview <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    eax 00000000  ebx 00000f58  ecx 00000f58  edx 00000006
    esi 00000f58  edi 0000000c
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
    eip b76fdc96  ebp b7762ce0  esp bf86ad40  flags 00000203
backtrace:
    #00  pc 0003bc96  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
    #01  pc 00000005  <unknown>
stack:
         bf86ad00  00000001
         bf86ad04  b8ad26d0  [heap]
         bf86ad08  00000015
         bf86ad0c  b76cfef9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_unlock+25)
         bf86ad10  b7762800
         bf86ad14  b775dfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
         bf86ad18  00000015
         bf86ad1c  b7707e21  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush+81)
         bf86ad20  00000000
         bf86ad24  b8ad26d0  [heap]
         bf86ad28  00000015
         bf86ad2c  05514454
         bf86ad30  00000000
         bf86ad34  00000000
         bf86ad38  b76cfd29  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+9)
         bf86ad3c  b775dfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
    #00  bf86ad40  00000006
         bf86ad44  00000003
         bf86ad48  b775dfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
         bf86ad4c  b76da436  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+102)
         bf86ad50  00000f58
         bf86ad54  00000f58
         bf86ad58  00000006
         bf86ad5c  00000000
         bf86ad60  b7762800
         bf86ad64  bf86ada4  [stack]
         bf86ad68  b76da3d9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+9)
         bf86ad6c  b775dfcc  /system/lib/libc.so
         bf86ad70  bf86adbc  [stack]
         bf86ad74  00000007
         bf86ad78  bf86adf8  [stack]
         bf86ad7c  b76da7fc  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+44)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Boa ! Este plugin tem histórico de muito crash em diversas situações. De uma visualizada no github deles e você verá....
Já testou outros plugins de webview, como o webview_flutter?

Comment: Olá Sérgio, obrigado pelo comentário...

Sim, conforme mencionei na descrição testei com alguns pluggins inclusive o webview_flutter, porém ocorre o mesmo problema.

Consegui com apenas um pluggin mas no qual não é nativo, logo, ele sobrepoe todos elementos em tela, inclusive app_bar e demais questões.

Acredito que seja algum problema relacionado a versão do próprio android, pois acima do 5.0 ele roda normalmente.